# Ubuntu 14.04 server has been compromised

Tags: 14.04

My server has been compromised. My VPS provider stopped the server because they found suspicious DDoS profile attack. If I restart the server, they will probably suspend it, because the DDoS attack will continue.. But I really need my emails from that server. (Using IMAPsync)

Could you recommend something in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest:

- Take an image of the server
- Start the image of the server in an isolated environment on a computer owned by You
- Copy the emails to external storage

If the disks of the server (which contains the emails) aren't part of the server, you might be able to `mount` the disks from another server, and get access to the emails without having to power-on the compromised server.

Afterwards, you should create a new server (don't use the compromised server any more)